# mongoose query regex to ignore middle character

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working with mongodb and  my data is stored as **day:"3/6/2020"**  i want to query the string that matches **day:"3/2020"** without the middle value or  omitting the 6 in **day:"3/6/2020"**. 
 such as

```
`myModel.find({"day": {$regex: "3/2020",  $options:" what option to pass here to ignore the `
` middle value"}});`
or any better way
 `model.find({"name": {$regex: search, $options:" regex options"}}, (err, users)=> {`
        `  res.status(200).send({users});`
```

**"3/2020"** to match any record with **3** and **2020** just as this "3/2020" matches with  **"3/6/2020"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
Solved. i solved it  splitting my date as in my schema
```
    qDay :{
        type:Number, default: new Date().getDate(Date.now)
    },
    qMonth :{
        type:Number, default: new Date().getMonth(Date.now) + 1
    },
    qYear :{
        type:Number, default: new Date().getFullYear(Date.now)
    }```

my query


```const getByDay = async (req, res)=> {
    console.log(req.body);
    merchantModel.find({$and:[{qMonth : req.body.month}
        ,{qYear: req.body.year},{qDay:req.body.day}]}).then((record)=> {
        if(record.length == 0){
            res.status(404).send({msg:'no record!'});
        }else{
            co`enter code here`nsole.log(record);
            res.status(200).send({record:record});
        }
    });
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use aggregation framework to convert the string date in to proper date, fetch months and years and match against that properly. Something like this

```
model.aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
        "convertedDate": {
            "$toDate": "$myDate" // mydate is your field name which has string
        }
    }
}, {
    "$addFields": {
        "month": {
            "$month": "$convertedDate"
        },
        "year": {
            "$year": "$convertedDate"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "month": 3, // this is your search criteria
        "year": 2020 // // this is your search criteria
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "month": 0, // Do not take temp added fields month and year 
        "year": 0 // Do not take temp added fields month and year 
    }
}])
```

This might look like a big query but I guess much better than doing string comaprision using regex. If your field is saved in date format, you could also remove the first stage in which you are doing `$toDate`. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, i will highly appreciate if you can can reference me to more example  to fit my understanding.

Comment: read - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/

I guess this should help you

Answer (score 0):

That might help you. We match the 3, than a number wich is one or two characters wide, then at the end 2020.

```
3\/\d{1,2}\/2020
```

https://regex101.com/r/jn4zwa/1

Comment: `model.find({"name": {$regex: search, $options:" /\d{1,2}\"}}`   does not workout.

Comment: Why are you searching for \d{1,2}? search for the regex i provided you: 3\/\d{1,2}\/2020

Comment: sorry about the above , i copied that from above .. below is my code   `  let yearString = req.body.year.toString();`
      `  let monthString = req.body.month.toString();`
       ` console.log('fire etting...', queryDate);`
      `  await FruitModel.find({"day": {$regex:` `queryDate,$options:"/\d{1,2}"}}, (err, records)=> {`
          `  console.log(records);`
          `  res.status(200).send({msg:"successs", record:records});`
          `})`

Comment: monthString +'\/'+'\d{1,2}'+'\/'+yearString; one of the first mistakes that could happen.

Comment: Are you familiar with escapings in regex?